# How to calculate percentage in CrystalReports based on the Total?

Tags: crystal-reports

**My View table is:**
Id int,
Name varchar(50),
Mark1 int,
Mark2 int,
mark3 int

I have added one formula field called Total and in that I have calculated the total marks. So my question is based on the total,how to calculate percentage??

**My actual result is:**

**Id name mark1 mark2 mark3 total**

---

1  ram    50    60   70   180

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate percentage in CrystalReports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45794117/how-to-calculate-percentage-in-crystalreports)

Comment: like I pointed out before: percentage is (x/y) * 100 what is the x and what is the y? Are your values already percentages? This is no different in Crystal.

Comment: I have calculated total. for ex my total is 180 in the sense,how to calculate percentage from that?

Answer (score 0):

You may use Running Total Field with Average option for your total